# NumberOfRowsInSection called twice - property "unset" on second pass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm struggling with understanding this one and hope someone can help me figure this out.

I've got a property called **replies** in my ViewController. This is loaded by another ViewController after the user clicks on a row in the table, and passes an XML node into a property on the new ViewController.

I have this code:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (replies == nil)
    {
        replies = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    if(replies.count == 0)
    {
        replies = [node elementsForName:@"question"];
    }

    return replies.count;
}
```

Replies is a property on the ViewController. NumberOfRowsInSection gets called twice during the load process. On the first pass I can see the property get populated. On the second it's empty, and the call to replies.count returns a "Message sent to deallocated instance" error.

I'm kind of confused by this - since the property was set during the first pass, what happened to my value by the time the second pass happens? This has been driving me nuts...

Comment: Show the declaration of `replies`. You need to declare a `strong` reference to it. Also, for any memory related questions, you should mention if you're using ARC.

Comment: If your `replies` is a property use it as a property self.replies.

Comment: Note in case of `replies == nil` both `if` branches will be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your property retains a strong reference to replies:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *replies;
```

and reference replies like following:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (self.replies == nil)
  {
      self.replies = [[NSArray alloc] init];
  }
  if(replies.count == 0)
  {
      self.replies = [node elementsForName:@"question"];
  }
  return self.replies.count;
}
```